# Vue.js component won't render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component that use `axios` to bring in some data into my page. The request for the data is never made. Here is my code:

In App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Prices/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Prices from './components/Prices.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Prices
  }
}
</script>
```

In Prices.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ info }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Prices',
  props: {
    info: String
  }
}
</script>
```

In main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
    data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response))
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

I am new to Vue.js, this is my first app and I am not sure what I am missing in order to get this to work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to assign the `data` property of `response` to your `info` property as follows :

```
 .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
```

and pass that property `info` via `props` to the child component :

```
  <Prices :info='info'/>
```

and change `app.vue` to this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Prices :info='info'/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Prices from './components/Prices.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
    data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  components: {
    Prices
  },
  mounted () {
    this.axios  //<--- use this.axios instead of `axios`
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
  }
}
</script>
```

and `main.js` :

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import axios from 'axios';
import vueAxios from 'vue-axios';
Vue.use(vueAxios,axios); //add Vue.use(axios)
Vue.config.productionTip = false new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data() {
    return {}
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Note**

you should also install `vue-axios` via :

```
   npm install --save vue-axios
```

and use it with `axios` like :

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import vueAxios from 'vue-axios';
    Vue.use(vueAxios,axios); //add Vue.use(axios)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide `props`

remove from `main.js` fetch task 
and do it in the app component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Prices :info="info"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Prices from './components/Prices.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      info: null
    }
  },
  components: {
    Prices
  },
 mounted () {
    axios
      .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
      .then(response => (this.info = response.data))
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: look to my answer and compare i added some comments inside the code

Comment: please check this solution https://codesandbox.io/s/wonw76ml47  and compare it to your own solution